# Who did what for the original "Shadowgate" on Macintosh and NES?

Tags: macos, gaming-history, nes, shadowgate

I am trying to determine who were actually involved in making the classic "Shadowgate" game for the Macintosh, and its NES port.

On MobyGames, I read:

> Staff: David Feldman, David Marsh, Terry Schulenburg, Karl Roelofs, Jay Zipnick, Todd Squires, Darin Adler, Tod Zipnick, Waldemar Horwat, Steven Hays

This is unusually vague. Usually, it says something about what each person did, but here, they are all just bundled together as a generic "staff".

On https://www.zojoi.com/who-we-are/ , apparently the current website for the company, two of them are mentioned: Dave Marsh and Karl Roelofs. They also link to their Wikipedia articles. From those, I get the perception that they were the ones solely or primarily responsible for making the original game for Macintosh.

But then what did the other people do? Why are they not mentioned anywhere except as "staff"?

Also, the same page claims:

> They went on to port Shadowgate and the other “MacVentures” (Déjà vu, Déjà vu II, The Uninvited) to no less than 10 platforms including the NES and Color Gameboy.

But the MobyGames page for the NES port of Shadowgate only lists two Japanese people: https://www.mobygames.com/game/1070/shadowgate/credits/nes/

... and that's for graphics and sound. Maybe that implies that Dave and Karl made the programming/"decisions", but outsourced specifically the graphics and audio for that port?

It's disturbing to me how little credit people got who made all these classics, and how difficult it is to find this out later. It's almost as if they were ashamed to be working on them, even though they had every reason to be proud of this game.

The Wikipedia article on Shadowgate does not explain anything further as far as I can tell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowgate

What did all the other "staff" members do on the game? Fetch coffee?